# Jenking not displaying build history from a single user

Tags: jenkins

1. Latest Jenkins 1.615. Server is working on FreeBSD (x64).
2. Open https://my_domain/**user**/my_user/**builds**
3. Chrome browser doesn't give any communication errors in the console.

And there are no builds for any user. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more information? That would be helpful for others to provide potential helpful answer.

Well, when I try on my own machine, it works fine for me.

Accessing http://localhost:8080/user/admin/builds return me all the builds executed by user `admin`

[image]

Comment: RSS feed is working alright and give results. 
I don't know how to debug the page. If you tell me what could I do about it?

Comment: I have tried if there are client side errors in browser console - there are no errors. So it should be on server side.